# Comments don't display in custom template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm coding a custom template for WordPress 3.5.1 on my local machine. I came to a section where I need to add comments so I added following to my index.php page 
 `<?php comments_template(); ?>` I have also included `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` and 
`<?php wp_header(); ?>` to support WordPress plugins. But when I check the page out I can't see any comments, even the default one (I also checked that it exists in database). Is there anything I am missing? What can affect display of comments? Do I need to include some additional stuff?

Also it's a single page website with static content (I edited header and footer to display dynamic content like title, meta data etc.., but as it is 1 page website I decided to use static content, not sure if it has something to do with the issue). Therefore there is 1 page on a server index.php which users see, I'm not sure if that is the issue, but could it be something to do with comments related to a post? however I still think that I should at least see a comment form on a page.

Comment: How are you populating the posts for that page? Or, how are you querying for comments?

Comment: @s_ha_dum page is populated by static content (content in markup), I know that's a bad practice, but that will do for client and it is a 1 page site. to display comments I use that <?php comments_template();?>
Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: It isn't necessarily bad practice-- depends. But you still must be querying for the comments if you are going to display them. How are you doing that?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I'm not sure I understand you, Isn't 'comments_template' function supposed to include query for comments? I am following series of tutorials where instructor doesn't create any queries, he just calls this function and default comments appear, however I can't see anything

Comment: `comments_template` will look for comments based on `$post-<ID`-- [see the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L848). It will return comments for some particular post in the Loop, based on the `$post` object. So, does this page have comments associated with it. Sounds like it doesn't? Still trying to work out what you are doing.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I think you are right, this page doesn't have any post object associated to it, it's just a index.php page with static content. Is there a way to associate to a certain post?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the information in the comments, especially that in your final comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to associate to a certain post?

You need to query for the post you want and build a Loop. It is really pretty simple.

```
$args = array(
  'p' => 188 // works on my server; use whatever ID you need
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);

if ($qry->have_posts()) {
  while ($qry->have_posts()) {
    $qry->the_post();
    comments_template();
  }
}
```

That should bring up the comments for the post you choose.

[You may need to enqueue `comment-reply`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) if it isn't loading on your page already.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Ok, sorry for being so full of questions, still new to these things. I created a page and assigned it as front-page. Still can't see any comments nor forms, do I now need to assign a post to that page or what?

Comment: Is this the same page we've been talking about?

Comment: Hi thnx, for help I did a research on the loop and finally got it working ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you invoking [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) at all on the single page? If not, WordPress can't query for comments as they're all attached to a specific post ID. WordPress also needs to know if comments for that specific post are on or off before it will display a form.

Your static content should be stored within a WordPress Page, with comments set to on. You define that page as the the front page in the Settings. (Settings -> Reading -> "Front page displays a static page"). On the template page, you'll use [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/) to output the content.

```
<?php if(have_posts():
while(have_posts()):
    the_post(); ?>
    \\ output goes here
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile();
endif; ?>
```